# sql report link with rs:Command paramaters not opening in JSF page

Tags: sql-server, parsing, jsf

I have a report that we need to link (which we've checked to be working) to in a JSF project, the link looks like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/report/summary&rs:Command=Render
```

However when we try to load the page that links to it we get the following error:

> The reference to entity "rs:Command" must end with the ';'

How can I link to the report within my pages and prevent it from trying to parse the rs:Command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page itself, try using `...&amp;rs:Command=Render`, not `...&rs:Command=Render`. The ampersand is a special character in (X)HTML, and should be encoded as such. That won't affect the running of the report when you hit the link.